# Cannot convert undefined or null to object or not length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If you put a value in every input, it works normally. However, errors appear even if only one input is empty.
nameValue.length, an error appears that you cannot work on the length.
Object.values(nameValue).length, the error  'Cannot convert undefined or null to object' appears.

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    nameValue: '',
    numberValue: '',
    contentValue: '',
  });

  const { nameValue, numberValue, contentValue } = values;

  const handleNumber = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;

    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (numberValue.length === 11) {
      setValues({
        numberValue: numberValue.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3'),
      });
    } else if (numberValue.length === 13) {
      setValues({
        numberValue: numberValue
          .replace(/-/g, '')
          .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3'),
      });
    }
  }, [numberValue]);
```

```js
const handleSend = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log(typeof stringify(nameValue) === 'undefined');

    const nameValueTrue =
      Object.values(nameValue).length > 4 ||
      Object.values(nameValue).length < 1 ||
      typeof nameValue !== 'string' ||
      typeof nameValue === 'undefined';

    const numberValueTrue =
      Object.values(numberValue).length < 13 ||
      Object.values(numberValue).length > 14;

    const contentValueTrue =
      typeof contentValue !== 'string' ||
      Object.values(contentValue).length < 2;

    const error = !e.target.value;

    if (nameValueTrue) {
      alert('이름을 확인해주세요.');
      console.log('name안');
    } else if (numberValueTrue) {
      console.log('number');
      alert('휴대폰번호를 확인해주세요.');
    } else if (contentValueTrue) {
      console.log('content');
      alert('내용을 확인해주세요.');
    } else {
      goto();
    }
  };
```

```js
<ContentBox>
          <div>Name</div>
          <ContentInput
            name="nameValue"
            value={nameValue || undefined}
            //value={nameValue || ''}
            //value={nameValue}
            onChange={handleNumber}
          />
        </ContentBox>
        <ContentBox>
          <div>Phone Number</div>
          <ContentInput
            name="numberValue"
            value={numberValue || undefined}
            //value={numberValue || ''}
            //value={numberValue}
            onChange={handleNumber}
          />
        </ContentBox>
        <ContentBox>
          <div>Content</div>
          <ContentInput
            placeholder="내용 입력."
            name="contentValue"
            value={contentValue || undefined}
            //value={contentValue || ''}
            //value={contentValue}
            onChange={handleNumber}
          />
        </ContentBox>
        <Submit onClick={handleSend}>Send</Submit>
```

Comment: In your useEffect, you're overwriting the whole values object to just be numberValue. You need to spread the object there too, like you have in handleNumber

Comment: `Object.values(nameValue)` when `nameValue` is a string or `undefined` doesn't make much sense. [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is for getting the values of properties of an **object**. Strings and `undefined` are not objects. If you just want the length of the string, use `nameValue.length`, although there is a **slight** difference around code units vs. code points. If that's important, perhaps `Array.from(nameValue).length` instead, it's more designed for the case of spreading out an iterable into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your useEffect, you're overwriting the whole values object to just be numberValue. You need to spread the object there too, like you have in handleNumber